# Git: checkout to 2 commit after a tag

Tags: git

Knowing the following scheme : 
[image]

Yellow line is Master branch. 
Red line is Develop branch.

I am on Master on tag 6.2.1. 
My need would be to get automatically the sha1 of the commit circled in blue, checking out to this sha1 and create my branch from this sha1. This commit is not the last commit of develop.

The thing to do could consists in :

- getting the sha1 of tag 6.2.1 : `git log --oneline | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1`
- getting the parent of tag 6.2.1 : called commit 'P'
- getting the following commit of 'P' called commit 'C1' which should be on develop
- getting the following commit of 'C1' called 'C2' also on develop.

Currently I have to manually go on Gitlab, get the related sha1 before checking out and then create my branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way, but there is a potential problem.

A tag name identifies a commit.

More specifically and precisely, a tag name like `v2.1` is the short version of the fully-qualified *reference* name `refs/tags/v2.1`, and any Git reference identifies some Git object.  All *branch* names, such as `master` which is short for `refs/heads/master`, are constrained to identify *only* a commit object.  Tag names usually identify either a commit object—Git call this a *lightweight tag*—or an *annotated tag* object, which then goes on to identify the commit.  In either case, the [special gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) `name^{commit}` refers to the specific commit, if you need that (usually you don't—Git figures out that, e.g., `git checkout` needs a commit and adds the `^{commit}` automatically).

The problem is, you don't want the commit the tag identifies.  You want a *nearby* commit.  You said "two commits *after*" and this is a problem: there's no such thing as a commit *after* another commit.  There are only commits *before* another commit.

#### Objection, your honor!

How can there not be a commit *after* a commit if there is a commit *before* a commit?  For instance, let's write down four commits in a row:

```
A <- B <- C <- D
```

In Git, commit `D` stores the ID of its *parent* commit, which is commit `C`.  So given `D` it's very easy to step back to `C`.  Likewise, `C` store's `B`'s ID, and `B` stores `A`'s.  (If `A` is the very first commit ever, there is *no* parent: you cannot step back, and `A` is a *root commit*.  A root commit is one that has no parent.)

The problem here is that there can be *more than one* commit before a commit, or after a commit, for that matter.  Instead of just the above, consider this graph fragment:

```
A--B--C--D---H   <-- master
    \       /
     E--F--G     <-- feature
```

Commit `H`, which is the *tip* of branch `master`, is a *merge* commit.  It has *two* parents: `D` and `G`.  When we examine commit `H` we see something like this (with different numbers):

```
$ git show master
commit 3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3
Merge: c13c783 20690b2
```

This means it has two parents, `c13c783...` and `20690b2...`.  *Which one is **the** commit before commit `H`?*

So the answer to the objection is that there isn't *a* commit before a commit, there are possibly-*many* (often 1, sometimes 2, rarer but occasionally zero, or three-or-more) commits before another commit.  Likewise, there may be none, or two or more, commits *after* another commit.

To find the commit(s) you *want*, you need more information.

#### More information

In general, moving backwards is easy.  The *first* (and often the *only*) parent of a commit is usually the interesting one, as it's the commit that was on the branch *before* that commit got added *to* that branch.  That is, while commit `H` has both `D` *and* `G` as parents, if `master` used to point to `D` and now points to `H`, it's `H`'s *first* parent we want.

[Gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) has a quick and easy syntax for following first-parents: you simply add a tilde `~` character and a count of how many first-parents to step back.  So to go two steps *back* from `v2.1`, following only first-parents, just write `v2.1~2`:

```
git checkout -b newbranch v2.1~2
```

and you're done.

Going *forward* is harder.  Git only stores backwards links, so what you need to do is provide a name-or-identity of a *later* commit, from which Git can work backwards to reach your known (tagged) commit.  For instance, if we have a tag pointing to commit `C` and we want to move forward two steps (to `D` and then to `H`), we would give Git *two* bits of information:

1. please end at `v2.1`
2. and start from `master`

and have it enumerate all the commits between those two points, and then pick the one two steps "closer to `master`" than the final one at `v2.1`.  Let's say at this point that there are even more commits on `master` now, so the drawing looks like this:

```
   tag:v2.1
      |
      v
A--B--C--D---H--I   <-- master
    \       /
     E--F--G     <-- feature
```

To find `H` this way, we use [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) and [yet more gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).  (By now it should be obvious that **learning gitrevisions syntax is critical to using Git**.)

```
git rev-list v2.1..master
```

The two-dot syntax here means "*don't* include `v2.1` itself", so this will list commits starting from master and working back to the commit after `v2.1`:

```
0fbc341...   # id of I
a9315c3...   # id of H
9911231...   # id of D
```

We take the last two of these IDs, throw away the last *one* of these IDs, and get `a9315c3`, which is the ID of `H`.

#### But there's still a potential problem

What if the graph looks more like this?

```
   tag:v2.1
      |
      v
A--B--C--D---------H--I   <-- master
          \       /
           E--F--G     <-- feature
```

We noted earlier that using the `~` notation uses the *first* parent.  We can do that here, using `git rev-list --first-parent v2.1..master`.  That will keep Git from listing `G-F-E`, which will make sure we find `H` instead of `E`.

It's a good idea to add `--topo-order` to the rev-list command as well, because otherwise these commits are listed in commit-date order, and if the date/times were ever screwed up on one of the computers involved in making the repository, the commits may be listed in the wrong order.

There is also the `--ancestry-path` option, which is useful in some cases (maybe not applicable to your own case): it makes sure that `git rev-list` lists only commits that are *descendants* of the left side of the `..` operation.  You would use this where the `--first-parent` is not wanted, e.g.:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C
      \        \  \
       D--E--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

If we want the commit "three steps" after tagged commit `*`, that could be `C` or `G`.  Using `git rev-list tag..branch` will print all of `A` through `H` (in some order).  Adding `--first-parent` will cut off either `G` *or* `C`—only one of those two can be the *first* parent of `H`—and if you want to look at both you cannot use `--first-parent`.  Adding `--ancestry-path` will make `git rev-list` omit `D-E-F`; the rest will still come out, in some order.  Adding `--topo-order` will guarantee that `B` comes out second-to-last and `A` comes out last (remember, Git is working backwards), with `C` and `G` in any order before them, and `H` first.

That's not a complete solution, but there *is no* complete solution, if you have a branch-and-merge-y graph like this.

Anyway, pick some subset of these options.  If you know your graphs are first-parent-able, then, e.g.:

`git rev-list --topo-order --first-parent tag..branchname | tail -2 | head -1`

will get you the hash you want.

(For another slightly subtle trick, add `--reverse` to reverse the printout order from `git rev-list` and then use `sed -n -e 2p` to print the *second* line.  Note, however, that you *cannot* use `git rev-list`'s `-n` flag here, as it counts and stops from the *unreversed* list, and we don't know how many commits there will be, we want the second-from-bottom, however many that is.)

Answer (score 0):

Open git bash, go to selected directory then run the following commands.
To get SHA1 run command

```
git log branchname --oneline
```

It will have the sha1 next to the commit message

[image]

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```

Comment: I edited my question : how can I automatically retrieve this sha1 ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Your answer is an alternative of getting sha1 manually (in command line instead of using gitlab) and your answer gets the sha1 of master branch and not develop. My need is get the sha1 of the commit on develop automatically. 
May be using git rev-parse or git merge-base which are commands that I don't master yet.

Comment: Yes that git log image was just an example of how to display a log for a particular branch i don't have your branch's so could not have done that. I do not know of any other way it can be done without finding the commit sha